# Visual Studio and TFS for Test manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

I have Visual Studio test manager installed in my machine, I have TFS Server installed on another server, I want to connect to that TFS server with new VS 2010.
Do I need to install the Visual studio 2010 full version or just the test manager?
I installed test manager and its asking a URL to add and I added the one we already have , but its not connecting to that site.
Do I need to isntall Full version and TFS on same machine??

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, all you need is Microsoft Test Manager (MTM). You need to make sure that you enter the full URL or just the server name.

If you put in "localhost" you will be connecting to "http://localhost:8080/tfs" so if your server is on a non standard port you may need to enter the full URI.

Try entering "http://localhost/tfs" as it is the most common customisation.

Comment: Hi, I tried with this. But Its not working. My TFS 2008 is sitting on another server. Do I need to install TFS2010 or just visual studio 2010 testmanager is enough? I have only this installed: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio Test Professional 2010 - ENU .
Is this enough??

thanks

Comment: @bisjom MTM only works with TFS2010. You will need to upgrade your TFS 2008 server to TFS 2010. If you need help with this please contact me directly on martin at hinshelwood dot com... ;)